# Finding Related Rows in Doctrine -- "Cleanest" Design?

Tags: doctrine

I'm new to Doctrine, and I'm trying to get my head around both Doctrine and Symfony at the same time, so please bear with me.

I have a "Sentence" object. Sentences can be "rated" (scored out of five) by Users. I'm modelling this with the fairly obvious design where I have a Sentence table, a User table and a Rating table. Each row in the Rating table represents one user's rating of one sentence.

```
Rating:
  ...
  columns:
    rating: { type: integer } # This is my score out of five
    sentence_id: { type: integer }
    user_id: { type: integer }
  relations:
    sfGuardUser: { local: user_id }
    Sentence: { local: sentence_id, onDelete: CASCADE, foreignAlias: Ratings }
```

That's working fine, but I'm struggling to find the cleanest way of asking questions of my model.

For example, in my code I have a logged-in User, related to my session, and I'm displaying a page representing a Sentence, which is also already sitting in a variable. I want to display the logged-in user's rating of that Sentence.

In raw SQL, effectively what I want to do is:

```
SELECT 
    rating 
FROM
    rating_table 
WHERE 
    sentence_id = {$sentence->id} AND user_id = {$user->id}
```

Now, I know I could just do this on the RatingTable, simply by writing a new query with a bit of DQL, or even using one of the "magic" finders. But that seems a bit clumsy and not very OO, when I already have a Sentence object in memory with a getRatings() method generated by Doctrine for me which must already have the rating I want in its Collection of "all ratings for this sentence".

Is there an easy, efficient way that I'm missing of doing something like `$sentence->getRatings()->findByUserId($user->getId())`?

Or is it actually sensible just to ignore the fact that I've already got a collection of "ratings for this sentence" in memory and dive back out to the database, ignoring them completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isnt a finder within a collection like that that im aware of (unlike with Propel)... if there is and I missed it in the Doctrine API then im going to leanr a blissful piece of code when someone posts it :-)

Having said that, IF you already have the collection loaded i would just add a custom method tot he model.. for example:

```
public function getUserRating($user){
  if($user instanceof Doctrine_Record){ // or sfGuardUser depending on how tightly you want to couple
     $user = $user->getId();
  }

  foreach($this->getRatings() as $rating){
     if($user == $rating->getUserId()){
        return $rating;
     }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: It's funny, but that looks almost exactly like my existing getUserRating function :) It was writing it, all the while thinking "I'm hand-coding my own foreach() loop to find a database object that has an index on the thing I'm looking for? I'm doing _something_ wrong" that prompted me to ask the question! It's nice to see someone confirm that I maybe wasn't that crazy. I'm going to leave this one open for a bit, though, to see whether anyone comes up with something that surprises us...

Comment: Well, I guess that's my answer! None of us are going to get much bliss :) What I might do in this case is ignore the the Ratings collection on Sentence completely as a bit of a red herring, and simply use the magic methods generated on RatingTable, e.g. findOneBySentenceIdAndUserId. That minimises the code, uses the DB and its indexes to find the rating, and should safely interact with the Sentence's rating collection, as Doctrine should only ever serve one instance of any given rating... Thanks again for the second pair of eyes!